# Custom Event in Custom Control (on variable changed)

Tags: c#, custom-controls, custom-events

I'm making a custom control including three buttons. Every button represents a tab. When I click a button to change to the tab corresponding to that tab a variable for the controll is uppdated, this variable is called "selectedIndex". How can I make a custom event that triggers when this index is changed?

I've seen solutions for custom events here but all of them is copies of already existing events such as Click-events. My problem involvs having an event on variable change".

Regards!

Comment: Is that variable a property on the object?  The object could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as a standard interface and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the property's setter.

Comment: Wery good idea, I will look in to how to make my variable a property. Thanks!

Comment: So I added a property for IndexCHanged:
`public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get;
            private set;
            //set { selectedIndex = value; }
        }`

Now, how do I add **INotifyPropertyChanged** for only this property so that it triggers an event when the value is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have your object implement the very standard [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  There's no rule which states that every property on an object needs to raise the `PropertyChanged` event, so just raise it for the one property in question.  Something like this:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If your .NET version doesn't support `CallerMemberName` then you can remove that and supply the property name manually:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
```

At this point any calling code can subscribe to the public `PropertyChanged` event on any instance of this object.  This interface is particularly handy because it's commonly used in lots of UI technologies for updating data-bound UI elements.  All the interface enforces, really, is a standard name for the event.  If you'd prefer, you can forgo the interface and just create a custom public event.  And just invoke that event any time your object logically needs to.  The structure of exposing an event and invoking it would be the same.

Comment: Thanks alot mr! I would like to make your first comment the answer as it is actually a good and straight forward answer to my question. But because I can't as it is only a comment I will mark your other response as the answer! Have a wonderful day!